# Jquery ajax call timeout.

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've an ajax call to set of urls to get html content. But some of the urls are taking long time to get the content, i'm okay to skip those which take more than say 1 sec.

```
    for (url in list) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        type: 'get',
        timeout: 1000,
        success: function () {
            //doSomething
        },
        complete: function () {
            //what to write?
        }
    });

}
```

Can you help me in how to abort the ajax call if it timeouts and execute the complete function.

Lemme know if i'm not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, change `$.ajax(function() {` to `$.ajax({`, because the argument you are trying to use is an object, not a function.

Since you specify a timeout in your options object, if the page doesn't respond in time, the ajax method will tell your `error` function so, as long as you specify one.

```
$.ajax({
  'url': yourUrlHere,
  success: function(){ /*do stuff*/ },
  timeout: 1000,
  error: function(xhr, status, err){ 
    //status === 'timeout' if it took too long.
    //handle that however you want.
    console.log(status,err); 
  }
});
```

See [the documentation for `$.ajax` here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), as it has a pretty good explanation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can abort the Request if that happens and go on to the next one..

```
var ajaxRequests = null;
for(url in list){
    var newRequest = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: '{}',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        var r = ajaxRequest;
        if (r != null && r != undefined) {
            r.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // what has to be done if the ajax request comes through
    },
    complete: function() {
        ajaxRequests = null;
    }
    ajaxReqs = newRequest;
}
```